# Неполадки во время проверки вводных данных в Си

Tags: c

Ввод данных совершается по частям, для каждой выводится отдельное сообщение,  после совершается проверка правильности ввода. Но в случае ошибки во время первой же части ввода, сначала выводятся все последующие сообщения, а затем сообщение об ошибке("Input Error.").

Вот так это выглядит:

```
Input Coordinates of First Point: 1 a
Input Coordinates of Second Point: Input
Coordinates of Point A: Input 
Error.
```

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
printf("Input Coordinates of First Point: ");
xy1 = scanf("%f%f", &x1, &y1);

printf("Input Coordinates of Second Point: ");
xy2 = scanf("%f%f", &x2, &y2);

printf("Input 
Coordinates of Point A: ");
xyA = scanf("%f%f", &xA, &yA);

if (xy1 == 2 && xy2 == 2 && xyA == 2)
{
    location = point_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, xA, yA);
    printf("Answer is %d", location);
}
else
    printf("Input Error.");
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сообщение об ошибке выводилось после окончания ввода. Либо чтобы перед "Input Error."  не выводились все остальные сообщения. Но не совершать проверку после каждого scanf.

Comment: нужно проверять правильность каждого ввода

Comment: "Как сделать так, чтобы сообщение об ошибке выводилось после окончания ввода." Так у вас же именно так и сделано! "Либо чтобы перед "Input Error." не выводились все остальные сообщения." Не понял. А как тогда пользователь узнает, что надо что-то вводить???

Comment: "Как сделать так, чтобы сообщение об ошибке выводилось после окончания ввода." Так у вас же именно так и сделано! "Либо чтобы перед "Input Error." не выводились все остальные сообщения." Не понял. А как тогда пользователь узнает, что надо что-то вводить???

Comment: @AnT Сначала выводится "Input Coordinates of First Point of The Line: ". Я ввожу некорректные данные, скажем не число, а символ. Затем я ожидаю, что выведется сообщение "Input Coordinates of Second Point: " и даст мне ввести данные. Потом также с третьими printf и scanf. И уже после того как я все ввел, сделав ошибку в первой строке, сообщение об ошибке. Но вместо этого он выводит все сообщения перед "Input Error", не давая возможности что-то ввести.

Comment: @AnT Я знаю лучше выводить сообщение об ошибке ввода сразу после этой ошибки(и более конкретно) , чтобы пользователь понимал в чем дело, но я хочу узнать есть ли возможность вывести сообщение после окончания всего ввода.

Comment: Выше требование - не проверять результат `scanf` - очень интересно перевести на обычный язык. Я хочу построить автомобиль, у которого временами могут отваливаться колеса. Как сделать такой автомобиль, чтоб водитель не заметил, что у него отвалились все колеса, пока не приедет в пункт назначения? Варианты с автомобилем с автоматической починкой колес на ходу или летающего автомобиля не рассматриваются. :)

Comment: @Harry Я в курсе. Выводить сообщение об ошибке и выходить из программы в принципе не корректно. Но меня интересует возможно ли так сделать в принципе.

Comment: Не проверяя результат ввода - не вижу никакой возможности...

Answer (score 0):

А теперь вспомним - что такое программа. Программа в общем смысле - набор инструкций, которые выполняются по порядку, кроме случаев конструкций управления потоком. Следовательно, если вы хотите проверить корректность первого ввода, то на следующей строчке нужно эту проверку и вводить. Язык за вас не думает, а просто позволяет компьютеру выполнить заданные вами команды.

Следовательно делайте так:

```
ввод1
проверка ввода1
ввод2
проверка ввода2
и так далее
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет в программе возможности вывода ошибки после ввода, у вас валидация в конце.
Есть 2 варианта для таких задач 1 - "костыль"

```
`
flag = 0;
 if(!= flag){
 printf("Input Coordinates of First Point: ");
 xy1 = scanf("%f%f", &x1, &y1);
 if(xy1!=2){
  flag=1;
 }
}`
```

Хоть я и не имею представления что такое xy1(надеюсь неведомая мне кастомная структура), тут я явно вижу что происходит, но код во истину монструозный
2-"Classic я бы даже сказал плезентли"

```
int format_input(void){
 .....//неведомый мне магический код
 printf("Input Coordinates of Second Point: ");
 xy2 = scanf("%f%f", &x2, &y2);
 ...//все валидации, возможные в нашем бренном мире
 if(все хорошо){
   return xy1;
 }else{
   кто это сделал? Что ты тут понавводил? а теперь выйди и введи 
   нормально!
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать так, чтобы сообщение об ошибке выводилось после окончания ввода. Либо чтобы перед "Input Error." не выводились все остальные сообщения. Но не совершать проверку после каждого scanf.

Пойдем экзотическим, *но чудовищным путем*.
Для этого используем "ленивость" логических операторов, 
правда, от проверок после каждого ввода это не избавит, 
но будет всего одно условие, только очень большое.:

```
if (
        printf("Input Coordinates of First Point: ") >= 0 &&
        (xy1 = scanf("%f%f", &x1, &y1)) == 2 &&
        printf("Input Coordinates of Second Point: ") >= 0 &&
        (xy2 = scanf("%f%f", &x2, &y2)) == 2 &&
        printf("Input Coordinates of Point A: ") >= 0 &&
        (xyA = scanf("%f%f", &xA, &yA)) == 2
   )
{ 
    //Выполнится только если весь ввод и вывод был успешен
    location = point_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, xA, yA);
    printf("Answer is %d", location);
} else {
    //Выполнится при первой же ошибке ввода/вывода
    printf("Input Error.");
}
```